# Where is System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler and System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler DLLs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, wif

I was wondering if someone could please help me locate the DLLs for the following classes:

```
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler
```

and

```
System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler
```

Neither classes seem to be in my current System.IdentityModel and System.IdentityModel.Services DLLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the `Object browser` in the `Visual Studio`, choose `.NET Framework 4.5` in the `Browse` dropdown and then find `System.IdentityModel.dll` and `System.IdentityModel.Services.dll` assemblies. Mentioned classes are located where they should be.

Verify that your project is targeted to `.NET Framework 4.5`.

Comment: Thanks. Marked as answered. To follow-up, any idea why I am getting this runtime error: " The value of the property 'type' cannot be parsed. The error is: The type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=456454464646' cannot be resolved. Please verify the spelling is correct or that the full type name is provided."?

Comment: @AllanHorwitz, you have an invalid `publicKeyToken` for the `System.IdentityModel` assembly. The correct is `B77A5C561934E089`.